# Python - Fastest way to compute average color of an image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a script to get the average color of a frame from a movie every second. At the moment I'm doing this using Pillows resize() function, however it is extremely slow (5-10 frames per second), which means analyzing an entire movie takes multiple hours. This is the code I've written:

```
def analyse_frames(movie_path):
    try:
        with open(MOVIE_TITLE, "w") as file:
            counter = 0
            video = cv2.VideoCapture(movie_path)
            total_seconds = int(video.get(
                cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)/video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
            succeeded, frame = video.read()
            while succeeded:
                video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, (counter*1000))
                succeeded, frame = video.read()
                img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                img_pil = Image.fromarray(img).resize((1, 1))
                color = str(img_pil.getpixel((0, 0)))[1:-1]
                file.write((str(color) + "\n"))
                counter += 1
                succeeded = counter <= total_seconds
                print(f"Frames analyzed: {counter} / {total_seconds}")
    except:
        print("Couldn't read movie file.")
```

Does anyone know of a faster way to calculate this average? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to convert the image into three numpy matrices (for RGB) and using numpy.average? That one should be pretty fast for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame.mean(axis=(0,1))`

gives you the mean BGR (or RGB) value of that frame, assuming it's a 3-channel numpy array.

Comment: (0,1) means to sum/average along axes 0 and 1, which are the axes for x and y. axis 2, which goes along color values per pixel, is left alone.